# Android load string in multiple steps depending on size

Tags: java, android, text

how can I read a text file which I got from uri (size is about 2Mb) in a special way without turning the screen black for a minute and then displaying the whole string ? My problem is that I set the textView text to whole string and that's why it lags. Is there any way to make it read it in small parts and then display them in small parts ? In a way that ES file explorer does.

Here is my actual, not very efficient and lagging code:

```
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String str = "";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    if (inputStream!=null) {
        try {
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txt.setText(buf.toString());
    }
```

Comment: yes, use TextView.append() method

Comment: same result and even more RAM consumption.

Comment: of course use it not once but several times with small chunks of data

Comment: okay, and how can I get small chunks of data ?

Comment: don't use "while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)" but rather read, say, 50 lines into a chunk and append that chunk

Comment: Thanks for that but can you please write down a whole code ? I got this code from website so I don't really know how to modify that without breaking things

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a loader.
Loaders are running on a different thread and therefore do not block the UIThread which creates your interface. Because you are loading a lot of data into memory, the system has to wait until it can display your interface. This causes the black screen. The problem can even force the system to shut down your app because it is doing to much work on it's main thread.

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html

There are different type of loaders.
You may need an AsyncTaskLoader or if you are querying a content provider a [`CursorLoader`](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html).

## Update1:

```
   package de.xyaren.fileloader;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {
    private TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        // File on my sd card
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.txt");
        Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Log.i("URI", myUri.toString());

        //Create arguments
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("URI", myUri);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);
    }


    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        final Uri uri = args.getParcelable("URI");

        Loader loader = new AsyncTaskLoader<String>(this) {

            @Override
            protected void onStartLoading() {
                forceLoad();
            }

            @Override
            public String loadInBackground() {
                InputStream inputStream = null;

                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

                if (inputStream != null) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));


                    try {
                        String str = "";
                        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            buf.append(str + "\n");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                return buf.toString();


            }
        };

        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String data) {
        //Interact with UI Here
        if(data != null)
            txt.setText(data);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {

    }


}
```

Comment: But this is a text file not a database

Comment: Loaders are not limited to databases. They also can load Images or other files from the internet or local storage.
Even for processing data before displaying it they can be used.

Comment: So then please provide a concrete example for my case please

Comment: I Updated the post with an example.

Comment: Provide full code and logcat errors. use http://pastebin.com/ for posting them in coments

Comment: I mean it won't allow me to compile it because there are different types of Loaders

Comment: I am not now on my pc

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be as follows:

```
txt.setText("");
if (inputStream!=null) {
    try {
        while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            txt.append(str + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```